# Does Direct3D 11 enable Z-clipping/discard by default?

Tags: 2d, directx11, depth-buffer

I'm rendering simple 2D figures in DirectX 11.1 and I cannot get Z-values to be rendered; all pixels with Z != 0 get discarded. I'm doing proper world transform as far as I know. X/Y translations work. Rotation over Z works.

Do I need to setup a depth/stencil buffer to avoid DirectX to discard all primitives with Z coordinates?

Thanks, I'll supply any additional information ,code or screens if required.

EDIT:

I've fixed D3D11_VIEWPORT minDepth and MaxDepth members to 0.0/1.0 (I was clearing both to zero). Now pixels with 1.0 < z < 0.0 are discarded.

EDIT 2:

My platform is Windows Runtime App (Win8.1 / WinPhone 8.1).

EDIT 3:
**Example screenshots.**

[image: Rotated triangle over the Y-axis (pixels with Z>1 discarded)]

*Rotated triangle over the Y-axis (pixels with Z>1 discarded)*

[image: Vertex at (-0.5,-0.5) with z=2. Clipped.]

*Triangle Vertex at (x=-0.5,y=-0.5) with z=2. Clipped and hidden.*

Comment: I'd suggest that you try changing the parameters of the `DepthStencilState` and try introducing a depth buffer, to see if things change. You can easily construct a DSS with default parameters by using the `CD3D11DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC` helper constructed with an `CD3D11_DEFAULT{}` argument.

Comment: Yes, to be more precise only pixels with 0 <  Z < 1 got rendered. I'll add this data to the question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you using a projection matrix, and if so, is it properly made or does it project all but a sliver of your geometry out of bounds?

Comment: No projection matrix is enabled in the vertex shader, only the world transformation one.

Comment: Created a depth/stencil buffer and still got clipping at Z > 1 !!!

Comment: Note that Direct3D clip space is a halfcube with [-1 to +1] on X and Y, and (0 to +1] on Z. You're only going to see Z between 0 and Z/W, which if you're showing unprojected geometry with W=1, is 0 and 1.

Comment: You were right about the clip space Z bounds! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lars Viklund stated, I didn't multiply my vertices in the shader to apply the projection transform, so I was constrained to the bounds of the clip space Z (0..1]. Adding a proper view and transformation matrix solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

A common mistake is to zero out `MinDepth` and `MaxDepth` of the `D3D11_VIEWPORT`, effectively clamping all depth to the near plane.

The default depth states are test enabled, write enabled, compare less.
See the [list at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In Direct3D 11, normalized device coordinates in clip space after W division run from
`[-1.0, +1.0]` on the X and Y axes, and `(0.0, 1.0]` on the Z axis.

If your post-projection geometry has a `Z/W <= 0.0` or `1.0 < Z/W`, the fragments will be clipped.

Comment: I was thinking of the same issue regarding  D3D11_VIEWPORT, it was zeroed in effect, I changed MinDepth to 0 and MaxDepth to 1, but no change.